# Creating models.UniqueConstraint in django, but the constraint is not applying

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

My table is defined as below.

```
class Role(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        to_field="email",
        db_column="user",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    vertical = models.ForeignKey(
        Verticals,
        to_field="name",
        db_column="vertical",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    product_domain = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductDomains,
        to_field="name",
        db_column="product_domain",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=[
                'user',
                'vertical',
                'product_domain'
            ],
                name='unique-permissions-per-user')
        ]
```

Here are the migrations that are generated

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Role',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('product_domain', models.ForeignKey(db_column='product_domain', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='verticals.ProductDomains', to_field='name')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(db_column='user', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, to_field='email')),
                ('vertical', models.ForeignKey(db_column='vertical', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='verticals.Verticals', to_field='name')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddConstraint(
            model_name='role',
            constraint=models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('user', 'vertical', 'product_domain'), name='unique-permissions-per-user'),
        ),
```

Serializers for the Role model is

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the interactive console for the same

[Link to console image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-cL4RDf6HJbUNuAVAz2BFEsM1Xmx0y6N/view?usp=sharing) (Unable to add due to less reputation )

Here the UniqueConstraint is not working, why?
I use models.UniqueConstraint in the same project many times but it doesn't work in this case.

My configuration is
Django - 3.0.4
Django Rest Framework - 3.11.0
Database - MySql

Please help and ask if any information is missing out.

Comment: Please add much more information on what's not working. Are you seeing an error? Or can you show a shell session where you insert two colliding records? Did migrations work fine?

Comment: Hello @AdamJohnson, I updated the question with more info kindly check it and ask if anything missing, as for that I'm not getting any error, the same record is being inserted into DB and yes migrations work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your logs don't show any attempt to insert the same record into the DB twice, just validation.

It appears Django Rest Framework does not import constraints from `UniqueConstraint`, and only has code to validate with the old `Meta.unique_together` constraint definition.

There is a tracking issue, [ModelSerializer not generating validators for constraints](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7173), on the DRF GitHub where you can follow the latest updates on adding support for `UniqueConstraint` validation.

Comment: `I use models.UniqueConstraint in the same project many times but it doesn't work in this case.`
DRF accepts models.UniqueConstraint.

Comment: Sorry afraid I can't help here :/

Comment: `meta.unique_together` has been deprecated. and yes the same colliding data is being saved twice. Thank You @Admam Johnson